# Mac OS X NFSD, portmap on a specific interface

Tags: macos, nfs

I'm using Vagrant and NFS is on to shared between the Virtual Machine and the host. Is there a way in Mac OS X that I can have NFSD/Portmap listen to a specific interface? for this instance, NFSD/portmap listen on the Virtual interface only.

Thanks